# "message": "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Tags: laravel, for-loop, foreach, arguments, laravel-api

```
public function saveHealthianOrderData($request)
    {
        
        try {
            $patient_id = empty($request->patient_id) ? config('api.current_user.patient_id') : $request->patient_id;
            $patientDetails = Patient::where('id', $patient_id)->first();
            $total_net_amount = 0;

      
            foreach ($request->test_details as $value)  {
                $total_net_amount += $value['net_amount'];
                
            }
}
}
```

Comment: $request->test_details is not an array. try to dd($request->all());

Answer (score 1):

You have many options to assign the iteratable to foreach

```php
if($request->has('test_details') && is_array($request->test_details)) {
    foreach($request->test_details as $somevariable){
    }
}
```

or second solution

```
$testDetails=collect($request->test_details)->toArray();
```

or just simply `dd($request->test_details)` and see if its array or not